# Convert JSON to data.frame using tidyjson

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON file that I want to convert to a table. It is easy to do with the `jsonlite` library. However, if the file is big, then the conversion takes a significant amount of time. So I am testing a `tidyjson` with the hope to speed up the process.

My JSON file looks as follows:

```
x = '[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "A": [
        {
          "B": "b1",
          "C": [
            "c1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "A": [
        {
          "B": "b1",
          "C": [
            "c2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
'
```

That's how I process it:

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
      
x %>% gather_array() %>%      
      spread_values(id = jstring("id")) %>%
      enter_object("A") %>% gather_array %>%
      spread_values(B = jstring("B")) %>%
      enter_object("C") %>% gather_array() %>%
      spread_values(C = jstring("C")) %>%
      select(id, B, C)
```

Outcome I get:

```
 ..JSON   id    B     C    
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 "\"c1\"" 1     b1    NA   
2 "\"c2\"" 2     b1    NA
```

Cannot figure out what is wrong with the code and why it doesn’t work well for C. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Expected output:

```
 id    B     C    
 <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     b1    c1   
2 2     b1    c2
```

**UPDATE 2:**
`jsonlite` way:

```
y = jsonlite::fromJSON(x)
cbind(id = y$id, do.call(rbind.data.frame, y$A))
   

  id  B  C
1  1 b1 c1
2  2 b1 c2
```

Not sure that it is the fastest way of using `jsonlite` in this case.

Comment: The expected outcome has been added.

Comment: I haven't worked with tidyjson. Do you mind including the jsonlite code that was too slow? It might be interesting for folks to benchmark the speeds

Comment: @Sergiy I don't see anything related to speed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html).  Are you sure that this will increase the speed?

Comment: @camille the jsonlite way has been added in the UPDATE 2.

Comment: @akrun I am testing the tidyjson way. Since my code doesn't work I don't know yet if it leads to a better performance.

Comment: @Sergiy can you try the python way with `reticulate` (as it returns a nested list and then you can make use of `rrapply`.  Based on the documentation in `tidyjson`, it is pitching to work on a broad range of nested objects (which also could decrease the performance if I am not wrong)

Comment: @akrun Appreciate your input. I'll test reticulate on the big file and will let you know. It may take some time.

Comment: That might just be a slow way to use jsonlite. The docs for tidyjson say it depends on jsonlite, so I don't know that it's necessarily going to be faster

Comment: @akrun Python way appears to be the fastest.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the timings.  If you don't mind, can you update the timings in your post with `system.time` or any of the benchmark packages i.e. microbenchmark or benchmark

Comment: I am posting results as a comment because the data I used for testing are different from the ones in the original post, although they have a similar structure. I have tested jsonlite way, python way, and tidyjson way on medium sized file (61.3 Mb) that has data for ~230K IDs. jsonlite - ~90 seconds, python - ~15 seconds, tidyjson - ~50 seconds. For tidyjson I used the code above, which doesn't provide a correct outcome. Also, python way requires some post-processing steps, so a couple of more seconds are needed to get the table in the required format. Anyhow, python way is the fastest so far.

Comment: I am trying one more way, will post an answer if succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `fromJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
fromJSON(x) %>% 
   unnest_wider(A) %>%
   unnest(C) %>%
   unnest(C)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id B     C    
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 b1    c1   
2     2 b1    c2
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(reticulate)
library(rrapply)
py_run_string(paste0("x = ", x))
rrapply(py$x, how = 'bind')
  A.1.C A.1.B id
1    c1    b1  1
2    c2    b1  2
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, it is very easy to get the table with jsonlite. But the problem is that it is very time-consuming in case the file is big. Therefore I am trying to avoid jsonlite.

Comment: @Sergiy I don't know whether tidyjson will improve the speed or not as  it is not mentioned in the docs.  I updated with another method in case that is useful to you

Comment: Although it is not an answer to the original question it is a solution to a primary problem, therefore I am accepting your answer. Thank you for your help!